# Close TCP connection with FIN flag

Tags: c#, sockets, go, tcp

I am developing a client-server application (client in C# and Go server) and I have been trying for a few days to solve a problem that I have when closing the TCP (TLS) connection that I have established for communication, the problem is the following, in Go I detect when a client closes the connection through the io.EOF read error, this is thrown when the TCP packet is sent with the `FIN` flag, but I can't get that when closing the connection in the c # client, this flag is sent, by the Otherwise the `RST` flag is sent causing a read error.

I am using the TcpCLient class to create the socket + SSLStream for the information stream itself.
The connection closure I am doing with:

```
sslStream.Close();
tcpClient.Close();
```

And what is being sent is the RST packet TCP instead of FIN:

[image: Wireshark capture]

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Comment: «when closing the connection in the c # client, this flag is sent, by the Otherwise the RST flag is sent causing a read error.» I can't properly parse this sentence, but I'd note that RST flag is sent by the TCP/IP stack (by the OS) _in response_ to some packet sent to an already dead connection: that is, there's no socket to receive the packet and so the kernel generates the RST packet in response. So I'd try to approach the problem from a different angle: to me, it seems like one part of the connection does not properly follow the shutdown sequence.

Comment: @kostix I think I understand what it says ... I am actually starting the shutdown sequence from the client, but I think I am not doing this startup right since the proper flag is not being sent, I have tried different shutdown methods (from the documentation of .NET) but none behave as expected ...